# Having issue while trying to pass two model to the same view at a time in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

I'm trying to create my profile type page for my simple blog site. I have two simple model class like this:

```
public class UserInfoModel
{

    public string UserName { get; set; }


    public string Email { get; set; }


    public string Password { get; set; }


    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }



}


public class NewPost
{

    public string PostTitle { get; set; }


    public string PostStory { get; set; }

}
```

I have created a joint model class of user & post to pass to view like this:

```
public class UserPostModel
{
    public UserInfoModel User { get; set; }
    public NewPost Post { get; set; }
}
```

The methods I wrote to retrieve the user & post info are like this:

```
public int GetUserID(string _UserName)
    {
        using (var context = new TourBlogEntities1())
        {
            var UserID = from s in context.UserInfoes
                         where s.UserName == _UserName
                         select s.UserID;
            return UserID.Single();

        }
    }

    public UserInfo GetUserDetails(int _UserID)
    {
        using (var context = new TourBlogEntities1())
        {
            var UserDetails = (from s in context.UserInfoes
                              where s.UserID == _UserID
                              select s).Single();
            return UserDetails;
        }
    }

    public Post GetUserPosts(int _UserID)
    {
        using (var context = new TourBlogEntities1())
        {
            var entity = (from s in context.Posts
                         where s.UserID == _UserID
                         select s).Single();

            return entity;
        }
    }
```

And finally I'm calling all my method from my controller action like this:

```
[Authorize]
   public ActionResult MyProfile()
   {
       var Business = new Business();
       var UserID=Business.GetUserID(User.Identity.Name);
       var UserEntity=Business.GetUserDetails(UserID);
       var PostEntity=Business.GetUserPosts(UserID);




       var model = new UserPostModel();
       model.User.UserName = UserEntity.UserName; // problem showing here
       model.User.Email = UserEntity.Email;
       model.Post.PostTitle = PostEntity.PostTitle;
       model.Post.PostStory = PostEntity.PostStory;




       return View("MyProfile",model);
   }
```

A run time error showing like " object is not referenced to a object type or null object". I worked ok in a very similar way while passing single model. Whats I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your UserPostModel

```
public class UserPostModel
{
    public UserPostModel()
    {
       User = new UserInfoModel();
       Post = new Post();   
    }
    public UserInfoModel User { get; set; }
    public NewPost Post { get; set; }
}
```

NOTE: check each value before set to model it should not be null.